# Read Encrypted Password in Java

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, passwords

I have the following code in javascript / nodejs that encrypt passwords. I need to read these passwords in java:

```
encryptPassword: function(password, salt) {
    var salt = new Buffer(salt, 'base64');
    return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 64).toString('base64');
}
```

I Used this method to create encrypted password for testing. this is the result (as java variables):

```
static String password = "123456";
static String salt = "CPvFo+klD9Vh2iE07JEGXA==";
public final String encrypted = "LtStqkNQjrr+P4V8fGtnauNJNOIB7t35O5I4a4/I9lFUnMR3ckbZyT85g/wO0Da9318Wrql/y1bsY2XdpXqx+Q==";
```

I tried to tranalte the encryption code above to java, using this http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/secure-password-storage-donts-dos-and.html   :

```
public static byte[] getEncryptedPassword(String password, byte[] salt)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    String algorithm = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
    int derivedKeyLength = 64;
    int iterations = 10000;
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, derivedKeyLength);
    SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
    return f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
}
```

Finally, I used apache codecs to set the 64 based string:

```
public static String getEncryptedPassword(String password, String salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
{
    byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(salt);
    byte[] encryptedPassword = getEncryptedPassword(password, bytes);       
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedPassword);
}
```

The tester is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    System.out.println(encrypted);
    System.out.println(getEncryptedPassword(password, salt));       
}
```

And the output is

> LtStqkNQjrr+P4V8fGtnauNJNOIB7t35O5I4a4/I9lFUnMR3ckbZyT85g/wO0Da9318Wrql/y1bsY2XdpXqx+Q==
>
> LtStqkNQjro=

As you can see, the java code produce something that is pretty much a prefix of the encryped password produced by the javascript.
I tested this on different complicated passwords, and got the same result: a string that is a prefix of the javascript encrypted password. Different passwords are not a prefix of each other.

Therefore, I think I am pretty much close. But I can't figure out what is missing.

Comment: Are you sure that Node's "crypto.pbkdf2Sync" is the same algo as Java's "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1" (especially the *WithHmacSHA1* part) ? I'm not an expert on these algos, but it seems that the Java version does some hash, so that the length of your result is shorter

Comment: The `keyLength` parameter for `PBEKeySpec` seems to specify the key size in bits. What are the units for the similar parameter in your js library? Bytes?

Comment: @superbob I think so. from the documentation (http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2sync_password_salt_iterations_keylen): "PBKDF2 applies pseudorandom function HMAC-SHA1..."

Comment: @OlegEstekhin I am not sure. the units are not specified in the java doc or in the javascript docs. therefore I assume it is not related to bit / byte but to the key length (term that is not language specific). docs: java - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/PBEKeySpec.html#PBEKeySpec(char[], byte[], int, int)    javascript - http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2sync_password_salt_iterations_keylen

Comment: You should have checked what happens when you specify 64 in js and 512 in java. The first base64 value is 64 bytes, while the second is 8 bytes (64 bits).

Comment: @OlegEstekhin - you are my man!! it works! please add your suggestion as an answer